# How to share a variable within an activity?

Tags: android, list, variables, spinner, settext

How can I grab the variable parent from OnItemSelected and use it in onClick?
I was to do this within onClick

```
result = parent.getItemAtPostition(pos).toString();
selected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected);
selected.setText(result);
```

I want that result to display in the selected textview when I click the button.
result will be the selected item in the spinner. This is first time using spinners so I have no clue.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

String[] test_array;
TextView display, selected;
Button submit;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.test_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

        }
    });
}
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {
            selected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected);
            String result;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            result = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();




        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
```

}

Comment: Declare the variable globally.

Comment: what problem u are getting using `spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();` on Button click to get selected item?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to declare the variable as a data member i.e. just like you have declared `test_array`, `display` and `selected` and not inside the `onItemSelected` method.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener
{

   String[] test_array;
   TextView display, selected;
   Button submit;
   String result;   // <------- declare the variable here and you can access it through out the activity/class.
```